# changing gcc parameters in netbeans 7.0.1

Tags: gcc, configuration, command-line-arguments

I have a single c file that can be compiled by the following command without any error:

```
gcc -o largeread main.c -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
```

But when I try to build this single file in one netbeans 7.0.1 application project I get the following error:

```
/home/mohsen/NetBeansProjects/largeread/main.c:45: undefined reference to `FT_Open'
/home/mohsen/NetBeansProjects/largeread/main.c:57: undefined reference to `FT_ResetDevice'
/home/mohsen/NetBeansProjects/largeread/main.c:58: undefined reference to `FT_SetBaudRate'
```

It means that some libraries are not added to my project. I have added `-L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib` to:
 `File->Project Properties->Categories->Build->C Compiler->Command Line->Additional Options` 
but I still have the same problem.  Does anyone have any idea?
thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794792/compiling-from-netbeans-fails-but-from-terminal-works/10812570#10812570